# ¿Como puedo verificar si una fuente está instalada en emacs?

Tags: emacs

Estoy configurando [neotree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree) en mi init.el con use-package. Éste requiere [all-the-icons](https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el) y la instalacion de las fuentes incluidas en este ultimo paquete con el comando (all-the-icons-install-fonts)... Mi configuración está como sigue...

```
(use-package neotree
:ensure t
:config
(global-set-key [f8] 'neotree-toggle))
(use-package all-the-icons
:ensure t
:config
(all-the-icons-install-fonts))
(setq neo-theme (if(display-graphic-p)'icons 'arrow))
```

Funciona bien, pero claro, cada vez que inicio emacs se vuelven a instalar las funtes. Llevo unas semanas dándole vueltas al asunto y no encuentro la manera de lanzar (all-the-icons-install-fonts) solo en caso de que las fuentes no estén instaladas... toda ayuda será bienvenida...

Answer (score 2):

Me respondo a mi mismo:
después de dar muchas vueltas buscando la función adecuada para evaluar si una fuente está disponible en emacs parece que encontré la respuesta... después solo era cuestión de un poco de código elisp.

La solución era tan fácil como evaluar

```
(if (member "all-the-icons" (font-family-list))
```

que devuelve nil si la fuente no está instalada. Al final el código ha quedado como sigue.

```
(use-package all-the-icons
:ensure t
:config
;;verificar la instalacion de las fuentes e instalarlas si no estan instaladas
(if (member "all-the-icons" (font-family-list))
nil
(all-the-icons-install-fonts)))
```

Quizá a alguien le pueda servir...